# Facebook Login from iframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

We built a service that's allow users to login via Facebook to check their status in the service and the status of their Facebook friends.

Now we're trying to share this service via an installable widget to our clients to allow them to embed it in their website.

We tried it but we found the issue about X-Frame-Options:

`Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?ancestor_origins=...&client_id=...&domain=...&origin=1&redirect_uri=...&sdk=joey&version=v3.2' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

The issue came out trying to call FB.getLoginStatus https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

Is there something in the Facebook app configuration that we are maybe missing?
Is there an alternative way to allow users login via Facebook with an embed widget?

Comment: Any update on this?